# sqlite insert into a range of columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider an SQLITE3 table named `Small` with column names `d_0, d_1, ..., d_n` (300>n>100).
Consider another table `Big` with column names `d_0, d_1, ..., d_n, d_n+1, ..., d_m` (1000>m>300).

Is it there an **easy / elegant** way to copy all elements of table `Small` into table `Big` so that values in column

`Small.d_0` are copied into `Big.d_0`,

`Small.d_1` are copied into `Big.d_1`,

...

`Small.d_n` are copied into `Big.d_n`?

Comment: Not unless you have a 1-to-1 for all the columns in the two tables, then you can usually leave out both the columns you select and the columns you insert into, but if you can't do that you must specify them all. Bad database design begets bad queries.

Comment: The "elegant" way would be to fix your schema so that each `d_n` value is a _row_, not a column. Databases don't scale well to massive amounts of columns; they scale to rows.

Comment: How about Just extending the current table (alter its columns to have more columns) ?

Comment: The most elegant way is to write some code that writes the query for you.